# Dynamically Creating a React Modal Using Portals

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

### *How can I append a component to a modal using a nested portal?*

I am building a page that displays several modals. I want to reuse the same modal but when a button is clicked, the app loads different content into the modal.

**WIP CodePen:**

https://codepen.io/jtsharpsite/pen/gorvjR

```
 render() {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
   this.props.children,
   domNode,
  );
 }
```

I have it pretty close to how I think it might work, but I cannot figure out how to append another component to an already appended modal component.

I have a button which calls a handler that opens the modal and specifies the component type.

```
<button onClick={this.handleShow.bind(this, "p3009", "product")}>
      Product 3009
</button>

<button onClick={this.handleShow.bind(this, "s1", "special")}>
      Special #1
</button>
```

The handler is in the App context and opens the modal sibling:

```
handleShow(modalId, modalType) {    
     this.setState({ showModal: true });
}
```

When the modal component mounts, I then try to append the Product when it mounts.

```
componentDidMount() {
   //TODO how to append to parent modal?
   modalRoot.appendChild(this.el);
}
```

How can I move the *`<Product>`* or the *`<Special>`* up into the *`<Modal>`*?

Comment: Maybe you should just render a single parent component to the portal and use this.children to set the buttons it renders.

Comment: What about making Modal a child of Product? Then each product component would have its own modal. Is there an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a parent-child pattern in the portal?

For example, make your children like this and just have `ModalDisplay` render its children. I don't know if what you are trying to do is possible because I think it requires portals to support fragments and I'm not sure if they do.

I don't know if I got the context of your question right but the idea is the same you have a single child that itself has children instead of having more than 1 child in the portal call.

```
<ModalDisplay>
  <Special title="special" text="text" />

  <Product title="product" pic="picture" />
</ModalDisplay>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. In the app class, there is only one Modal component. I want to avoid including all of the child components because there are like 30 different modal layouts and I don't want to render them all each time. I did see a pattern where instead of the button calling the click, there would be a component that would construct a modal with its own handler, but I don't know how to wire that up or if that is the way to go or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a reusable modal form... Theres a lot here you don't need, but just pay attention to the handleSubmit. Within the handleSubmit we call onComplete() which can be any function we pass through to the reusable modal when we call it, based on what function we want our modal to do... in our case it was capturing username, password, etc.

```
class ReusableModalForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
    };
  }



  handleChange(e) {
   let {name, value} = e.target;
   this.setState({
     [name]: value,
     usernameError: name === 'username' && !value ? 'username must have a value' : null,
     emailError: name === 'email' && !value ? 'email must have a value' : null,
     passwordError: name === 'password' && !value ? 'password must have a value' : null,
   });


 }

 handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   this.props.onComplete(this.state)
 }

  render() {

    return (
     <Modal
       open={this.state.createAccountModalOpen}
       trigger={<Link size="m" theme="bare" href="#" className="main-menu-item" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>{this.props.buttonText}</Link>}
       closeIcon
       onClose={() => { this.setState({
           createAccountModalOpen: false,
       }); }}
   >
       <Header icon='add user' content='Create account' />
       <Modal.Content>
           <Form />
       </Modal.Content>
       <Modal.Actions>
           <Button color='green' onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
               <Icon name='add user' /> {this.props.buttonText}
           </Button>
       </Modal.Actions>
   </Modal>
    );
  }
}



export default ReusableModalForm;
```

Based on this logic, you could construct a modal with a series of "trigger texts" to only render certain things based on what kind of props are passed down when you use your reusable modal.

Example.

```
<ReusableModal triggerText={'showAdress'} onComplete={this.showUsersHomeOnGoogle} />
```

Then in your reusableModal somewhere....

```
{this.props.triggerText === showAdress ? this.setState=({showHomeAdressPortion: true)}
```

UPDATES

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showModal: false };

    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleHide = this.handleHide.bind(this);
  }

  handleShow(modalId, modalType) {
    console.log(
      "Append content with ID: " + modalId + " of component type: " + modalType
    );
    //Here you should do a "fetch" first and grab your entire product information based on chosen ID and store it to state as an object...
    //setState({activePortal: someContentObject})
    //Then... I would use promise or aync await, show modal...
    //Have Modal display from this state object
    this.setState({ showModal: true, activePortal:  });

    //if it is a product
    if (modalType == "product") {
      //fetch additional images and add to state
      //add images to {product.additionalPics}
    }

    //TODO re-render the modal with the appending element portal
  }

  handleHide() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  render() {
    //console.log("RENDER App");

    // Show a Modal on click.
    const modal = this.state.showModal ? (
      <Modal>
        <div className="modal">
          <div className="modal-content-wrapper">
            {/* I think what you're asking to do here is display basically "any" information that comes from a product fetch. This isnt possible without templeting somehow.. You will have to hard code like "title" "body" "image" into this modal...
            <h1>this.state.activeProduct.title</h1>*/}
            {/* CONTENT NEEDS TO GO HERE SOMEHOW */}
            {this.props.children}
          </div>

          <button onClick={this.handleHide}>Hide modal</button>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    ) : null;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to swap out and load in entire complex layouts--each as its own component. Each modal is like a mini-app that does all sorts of things. I want to re-use the modal shell that has a portal that appends the content of the component into the shell. I'd like to avoid passing content through state since there would be a lot of html in each child component.

Comment: What are you showing exactly in the modal? Are you like showing some other html page like google? I'm confused on your end goal, you have to be passing state through unless you want to use REDUX (which I love btw), or you're displaying data from an API call, but that also requires you to pass state through.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I meant setting state explicitly for the content. I've created a CodePen that shows how I am trying to append a Product and a Special component inside the Modal. https://codepen.io/jtsharpsite/pen/gorvjR if that helps.

Comment: Checkout my comments in the UPDATES from your code.

Comment: Your comments make sense. What if I made `<Product>` and `<Special>` the parent of the modal? Each had a child `<Modal>` which in turn had the contents of the modal as a child: <Product><Modal><ProductDetail title={itemlist.props.title} /></Modal></Product>

Comment: Yea, that would work, and is essentially what myself and the first answer suggested, without an extra step you're adding. Either this is like a learning assignment, or you are wayyyyy above my knowledge level of React because the basis of this project is really not conventional. (Not being rude or anything! making a joke!) Also, when using your example here in the comments, pass the entire product obj through as props to save yourself time. so product={itemlist} then you have access to all the props inside your modal.